# Scala - parse phrase - parsing combinator or NLP?

Tags: scala, parsing, nlp

I would like to answer questions such similar to these examples:

- "23 jul cinema in Paris" --> returns the list of cinema shows in Paris for this date.
- "23/07 cultural activities New Jersey" --> returns the list
- "next week concert of classical music Spain" --> returns the list

How do I go about this? Should I use ScalaNLP, a parsing Combinator or something else?

My second question is how are date formats parsed?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed because it is very broad, has no code you've tried (but doesn't quite work) and is actually two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maluuba's Natural Language API may be helpful for you http://dev.maluuba.com/

It extracts important keywords and intents from sentences and returns them in an easily read format.

For the phrase "23 july cinema in Paris" the response is:

```
{
    entities: {
        dateRange: [
            {
                start: "2014-07-23",
                end: "2014-07-24"
            }
        ],
        location: [
            "paris"
        ],
        theatre: [
            "cinema"
        ]
    },
    action: "ENTERTAINMENT_MOVIE",
    category: "ENTERTAINMENT"
}
```

It would be up to you to connect this to a movie data provider that has films for Paris.

Comment: This API is very sexy :)